# Airflow exclude task from downstream dependency or reference job outside of subdag

Tags: triggers, dependencies, airflow

I am currently trying to build a data pipeline in airflow that has many sub-dependencies. I've created subdags (and subsubdags) to achieve the functionality that I want. One thing that I can't figure out, however, is **whether I am able to reference a downstream task from within a subdag.**

I've included a picture of data pipeline: [Data pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VV3q.png)

`task e` needs to be triggered by `task c` but has no downstream dependencies. I can't find a way to reference a task from a higher level within a subdag. Is there a way to do this?

As a work-around, for now I have just placed `task e` within the subdag with tasks a, b, c, and d. `task f` should be triggered when `task a`, `task b`, `task c`, and `task d` are successful, but it should not matter whether `task e` has succeeded or failed. Can I set `task f` to have the trigger `one_failed` and specify the `task_id` of the accepted failure?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by specifying the `task_id` of the accepted failure? Do you mind putting some sample code to show how you are doing this right now?

Comment: Maybe you can extract relevant bits for programmatically triggering an external task as they do in Airflow CLI's [run command](https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#run). References from `cli.py` are [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/bin/cli.py#L2247), and [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/bin/cli.py#L496). But do note that this can cause unintended side-effects in a SubDag + already running parent dag scenario